# What is the recommended way to guard against resource leaks in the context of ThreadAbortException?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, using, threadabortexception

I'm working on improving the exception-safety of a piece of code and I realized that a raised `ThreadAbortException` may cause undesired resource leaks, even when guarding resources with the C# `using` construct.  For instance, consider the following code (which could be running in a separate thread).

```
using (TextWriter writer = CreateWriter(filename))
{
    // do something with the writer.
}

TextWriter CreateWriter(string filename)
{
    return new CustomWriter(File.OpenWrite(filename));
}
```

If the thread running this code is abnormally terminated, then I would like the file handle referenced by `filename` to be closed immediately.  Can I do this without replacing the use of the `using` construct with a try/finally block?

My assumption is that `ThreadAbortException` may be raised at anytime, which means I should pay attention to what is happening between statements.  While I can guard against the exception in `CreateWriter` with a try/finally block, the `using` construct won't do the same until after the expression in the parenthesis is evaluated, meaning the file resource is left open if the exception occurs immediately after `CreateWriter` returns.

I understand that a finalizer will ultimately release the file handle, but I am wondering if there is a deterministic way to address this issue without catching `ThreadAbortException` in each place that `CreateWriter` is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tradeoff.

1. Be sure to close all resources immediately, even in the presence of ThreadAbortException
2. Have simpler code, but temporarily leak resources if Abort() is called

I assume that you are not calling Abort, and just want a way to be safe if someone else does. If you are calling Abort, then I'd advise that you don't.  This isn't the only problem you will run into.  There are other [problems with Abort in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx).

#2 is a valid choice because callers of Abort() should expect this.

If you want to choose #1, then I don't think even a simple try/catch will help.  If the ThreadAbortException can happen everywhere, then it can still happen after the file is opened (inside File.OpenWrite()) and before you can assign it to a variable that you can call Dispose() on -- you will have the same problem as using in your code.

You need semantics like

```
  using (var handle = GetUnOpenedHandle()) {
        handle.Open(); // this can't involve assignment to any field of handle
  }
```

I'm not sure this is possible.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the deterministic way of preventing this is by not using `Thread.Abort`. Ever. Signal to your threads that is is time to stop, and let them terminate gracefully. `Thread.Abort` is a great big red-herring, placed in the API solely to trip you up. ;)

http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2004/11/12/cancellation

Comment: To be fair, MSDN also warns against using it. It is maintained for backw compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases (but definitely not all) you *could* guard against a `ThreadAbortException`. Most of the critical code in the .NET BCL does this fairly well already. The problem is that it is *really* hard to get right. And for this reason most people recommend, and rightly so, to avoid aborting threads. Starting in version 2.0 the CLR made thread aborts a lot more tolerable and introduced a new set of APIs to help code authors guard against them. Take a look at [Constrained Execution Regions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228973.aspx) for an in depth look at how all of this works.

I believe you are correct about your concerns with the example of the `using` block. For constrained execution regions to work correctly the out-of-band (asynchronous) exception must occur from within a `try` block. But, because of the way `using` expands out the expression is evaluated outside of the `try` block. Contrast that with the expansion of the `lock` block which evaluates the expression from within the `try` block. Well, that is true [with version 4.0 of the framework](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/03/06/locks-and-exceptions-do-not-mix.aspx) anyway and that was changed specifically to guard against these exceptions.

So the question is why was the same change not made with the `using` block. [According to Joe Duffy](http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/PermaLink.aspx?guid=c1898a31-a0aa-40af-871c-7847d98f1641) this was an acceptable omission because the assumption is that thread aborts should *always* be followed by a termination of the AppDomain which would fire off the finalizers anyway.

So yes. Your code is not tolerant of out-of-band (asynchronous) exceptions. But, the prevailing wisdom from those smarter than me is that it should not have to be.

Answer (score 0):

A thread abort is most often used in the case of a fatal error, so your response should probably be to let your application terminate.  If your trying to stop your own threads cleanly, use Thread.Join().